# Heroku app custom domain points to empty root

Tags: heroku, dns

I've set up my app on Heroku. Everything loads fine when I access the herokuapp.com domain.

I've added my own domain to the app and added the CNAME as instructed but when I go to the subdomain it's just showing an empty root.

[image: empty root]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here!

I've checked the domain is added to the app running `heroku domains` in terminal and it's there.

This is the first time I've published an app on Heroku but I've followed the instructions and I can't see what the problem is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding another CNAME record in the domain provider account and creating the subdomain in there, rather than from the server.